# PostgreSQL function returning a table without specifying each field in a table

Tags: postgresql

I'm moving from SQL server to Postgresql. In SQL Server I can define table-based function as an alias for a query. Example:

```
Create Function Example(@limit int) As
Returns Table As Return
Select t1.*, t2.*, price * 0.5 discounted
From t1
Inner Join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
Where t1.price < @limit;
GO
Select * From Example(100);
```

It gives me a way to return all fields and I don't need to specify types for them. I can easily change field types of a table, add new fields, delete fields, and then re-create a function.

So the question is how to do such thing in Postgresql? I found out that Postgresql requires to explicitly specify all field names and types when writing a function. May be I need something else, not a function?

Comment: The type of `SomeTable.*` is `SomeTable`. If you use the `TABLE(…)` keyword, you have to specify the columns.

Answer (score 6):

Postgres implicitly creates a type for each table.  So, if you are just selecting from one table, it's easiest to use that type in your function definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int, value int);

CREATE FUNCTION mytest(p_id int) 
RETURNS test AS 
$$ 
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = p_id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

You are then free to add, remove, or alter columns in test and your function will still return the correct columns.

EDIT:
The question was updated to use the function parameter in the limit clause and to use a more complex query.  I would still recommend a similar approach, but you could use a view as @Bergi recommends:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (a int, b int);
CREATE TABLE test2 (a int, c int);
CREATE VIEW test_view as SELECT a, b, c from test1 JOIN test2 USING (a);

CREATE FUNCTION mytest(p_limit int)
RETURNS SETOF test_view AS
$$
SELECT * FROM test_view FETCH FIRST p_limit ROWS ONLY
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

You aren't going to find an exact replacement for the behavior in SQL Server, it's just not how Postgres works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to deal with `SELECT *, some, more, fields FROM test`? or `SELECT t1.*, t2.*, some, more, fields FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2`?

Comment: @Raider Then you should consider using a view, or you will have to spell out the columns

Comment: @Raider I updated my answer to show how you can use a view.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the function frequently, I'd suggest to use view instead of a function. Because every time you re-create a function, it gets compiled and it's a bit expensive, otherwise you're right - Postgres requires field name and type in functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW example AS
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*, price * 0.5 discounted
    FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE price < 100;
```

Comment: View doesn't match my requirements, because my queries are more complex, like `Select ... From ... Outer Apply (Select Top 1 From ... Where Date < @Limit Order By Date Desc)` there the @Limit is a function parameter

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Example(_id int) 
RETURNS RECORD AS
$$
DECLARE 
data_record RECORD;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO data_record FROM SomeTable WHERE id = _id;
  RETURN data_record;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: I get an error trying to select values from this function: "SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
  Position: 15
  ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
  Position: 15
  ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
  Position: 15

Comment: records are flexible, but difficult to deal with.  You do need to provide a column definition list when using them.